# What are these processes used by the GPU that appear when I run nvidia-smi?

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I see that there are five processes, but two of them seem equal, but with different PID and memory usage, what I want to know is what are these processes that are using my gpu, specially the `...token=...` one.

[image]

Comment: the output of `ps -fp 2239` would help (obfuscated, if needed), since the bulk of the process name is elided or masked in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The first four processes are your GUI (windowing, etc.) and the last one is probably Chromium.

Comment: I can verify that this is correct. In my case the ...-token line was the electron app "git kraken" whilst Chrome and another electron app showed up in the nvidia-smi process list under "...quest-channel-token=[0-9]*"